# Unable to paste a value in InstallWizard (running as System user) that i copied from notepad (running as Administrator) in Windows server 2016

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-installer, clipboard, windows-server-2016

Paste option is disabled on my InstallWizard

I have a MSI installer, it will invoke InstallWizard (Running as System user) on installation to get some input from user. When i tried to install it on Windows Server 2016, paste option is disabled on installWizard's InputText. And then i noticed I could paste a value that copied from the notepad(Running as system user) but not from notepad (Running as Administrator). I have few doubts on it.

1. Why this case is happening only on that machine(have not tried on other Windows 2016 machine)
2. How could i make it work.
3. I saw CreateProcessAsUser on internet which will create a process as logon user. Is this a correct way to solve this problem